# How to choose cross_val_predict method using try/except in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, scikit-learn, try-except

I am really curious how can I choose a method for cross_val_predict in a loop. I need decision_function for linear and predict_proba for binary.

Here is my code which I run for each classifier in a loop, fitting, getting accuracy, etc.

```
dict_models = {}

for classifier in list_of_classifiers:

# Here some code for fitting,accuracy,etc.

try: 
    x = 'decision_function'
except AttributeError:

else:
    x = 'predict_proba'

        cross_val_pr = cross_val_predict(classifier,X_train,
                                         Y_train,cv=5, method = x)

# Here is some code to put all the results in a dictionary for a model
```

My question is: how to choose the method according to the model? Maybe I am missing some default option in scikit? The current method just keeps using predict_proba without trying decision_function if the exception is raised.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `try: except:` at all in this code. I would create a separate list of models that use each and iterate them separately

Comment: What do you mean by separately here? I just want to have it in one dataframe after all so i can pass it get ROC in batch, not one by one.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, `linear_models=[mod1, mod2, mod3]; binary_models= [mod4, mod5, mod6]` then in your loop you make a conditional `if current_model in linear_models: cross_val_predict(...method = decision_function) else: cross_val_predict(...method = predict_proba) ` or similar.

Comment: @G.Anderson sounds simple and will work most probably, just want to have it automatically choosing instead of specifying which will require further manual appending to the list if models change. Maybe there is a way to get classifier type and then pass method accordingly through if?